# Hashing tuple in Python causing different results in different systems

Tags: python, hash

I was practicing tuple hashing. In there I was working on Python 2.7. Below is the code:

```
num = int(raw_input())
num_list = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
print(hash(tuple(num_list)))
```

The above code results in

```
>>> 2
>>> 1 2
>>> 3713081631934410656
```

But at my local PC where I am using Python 3.4 the answer is

```
>>> 1299869600
```

The code is accepted but I could not find out what causes the different results. Is this for different version of Python?

Comment: I tried with many different 2.x versions of hash on different machines right now. It shows the same result. While different versions of python3.x show a different result.

Answer (score 1):

The `hash()` may return different values for the same object on different OS, architectures, Python implementations and Python versions.

It is designed to be used only within a single Python session, not across sessions or machines. So you should never rely on the value of `hash()` beyond this.

If you need hashing that yields the same results everywhere, consider checksums such as:

- MD5 or SHA1,
- xxHash which per its author provides stable results across multiple OS and architecture, be it little or big endian, 32/64 bits, posix or not, etc.)
- or with some caution Murmur as some versions may yield different results on different architectures. For instance I experienced this fist hand when porting a C Murmur2 to an IBM S390 Linux install (of all odd places!). To avoid issues I ended instead coding a slow but arch-independent pure Python implementation on that OS rather than a C implementation.

Comment: Comment on xxHash is incorrect : result is stable across multiple different OS and architecture, be it little or big endian, 32/64 bits, posix or not, etc.

Comment: @cyan you are right and has the author of xxHash I must thank you ++ for chiming in: I added "with some caution" as I bumped in endianness issues in the past. For instance I experienced this fist hand when porting a C Murmur to an IBM S390 Linux install (of all odd places!). To avoid issues I ended instead coding a slow but arch-independent pure Python implementation on that OS rather than a C implementation.